# Linux Bash and Scripting - Count rows from text file

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, awk, putty

I'm having issues with displaying the row count displayed from a script I am currently working on and I am using Putty. This script reads a text file that looks similar to

```
user1|login|1
user2|login|1
user1|testing tests|10
user1|voiding tests|10
user2|logout|1
user1|logout|1
```

Currently my awk looks like

```
awk -F '|' '$1 == "user1" {sum += $3} END {print "user has run " NF "
processes for a total of "  sum " minutes" }' textfile
```

Currently this is supplying me with 
"user1 has run 3 process for a total of 22 minutes"

I need it to properly count the rows which should be four if my math is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NF is the "number of fields", i.e. the number of columns. In this case, each line has 3 columns, hence the output is always 3, regardless of the number of matches. You need to have an additional count for each match encountered, i.e. `proc` below.

```
$ awk -F '|' '$1 == "user1" {proc += 1; sum += $3} END {print "user has run " proc " processes for a total of "  sum " minutes" }' textfile
user has run 4 processes for a total of 22 minutes
```

Comment: Yeah, this cleared it up. Not sure why I was fixated on NF and didn't think of adding another count... Thanks a bunch!

Comment: For clarification: `NF` in the `END` section , if defined at all, has the field count of the last line.

Answer (score 0):

For the given example, try:

Just for one user:

```
awk -F'|' '$1=="user1"{i=$1;u[$1]++;m[$1]+=$3};END{print i,"processes:",u[i],"minutes:",m[i]}' file1
user1 processes: 4 minutes: 22
```

For all users:

```
awk -F'|' '++u[$1]{m[$1]+=$3};END{for (i in u) print i,"processes:",u[i],"minutes:",m[i]}' file1
user1 processes: 4 minutes: 22
user2 processes: 2 minutes: 2
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that NF is not the number of lines that were matched but the number of fields (columns). You could, for example, define another variable similar to "sum" and use that to count.

Comment: You mean, like my answer that I posted 5 minutes before this one?

Comment: Congratulations for being faster. Your answer was not there yet when I started writing mine.